# Navigation: how to make a robot follow a path

Tags: slam, navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am a beginner  in ros.

I should make a robot follow a path giving in the simulator rviz. How can i do this in ros ???

Pleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeease can some one help me!!

Thank's for helps.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272680/navigation:-how-to-make-a-robot-follow-a-path/) by [أسامة الادريسي](https://answers.ros.org/users/30880/%D8%A3%D8%B3%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AF%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%B3%D9%8A/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2017-10-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A good place to start is the [navigation tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials).

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5